# UNICODE_STRING to wchar_t* null terminated

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode-string, wchar

I want to use the buffer from a `UNICODE_STRING`, but it seems I cannot just directly use it, by copying reference, because sometime I can see that there are null bytes in the middle of a string, and `Length` is greater than what I see in the debugger. So if I do this

```
UNICODE_STRING testStr;
//after being used by some function it has data like this 'bad丣\0more_stuff\0'

wchar_t * wStr = testStr.Buffer;
```

I will end up with `wStr = "bad丣";`
Is there a way to convert this to the null terminated, valid `wchar_t*`?

Comment: In which encoding is the unicode string?

Comment: So you have a [double-null terminated string](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443). Not that unusual.

Comment: It works for any string system that uses `0` as a termination character.

Comment: IoW, you can't convert it to a `wchar_t *` because it contains more than one string.  You could convert it to an array of `wchar_ t *` if you wanted.

Comment: @2501: The character encoding is not interesting. If you insist that it is, it's UTF-16LE. The same as `wchar_t` for any compiler targeting the Win32 platform.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: [UNICODE_STRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518.aspx) is a **counted string**, not a double-null terminated string (although it can store one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `wchar_t*` is just a pointer.  Unless you tell the debugger (or any function you pass the `wchar_t*` to) exactly how many `wchar_t` characters are actually being pointed at, it has to stop somewhere, so it stops on the first null character it encounters.

`UNICODE_STRING::Buffer` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, but it can contain embedded nulls.  You have to use the `UNICODE_STRING::Length` field to know how many `WCHAR` elements are in the `Buffer`, including embedded nulls but not counting a trailing null terminator if one is present.  If you need a null terminator, copy the `Buffer` data to your own buffer and append a terminator.

The easiest way to do that is to use `std::wstring`, eg:

```
#include <string>

UNICODE_STRING testStr;
// fill testStr as needed...

std::wstring wStrBuf(testStr.Buffer, testStr.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
const wchar_t *wStr = wStrBuf.c_str();
```

The embedded nulls will still be present, but `c_str()` will append the trailing null terminator for you.  The *debugger* will still display the data up to the first null only, unless you tell the debugger the actual number of `WCHAR` elements are in the data.

Alternatively, if you know the `Buffer` data contains multiple substrings separated by nulls, you could optionally split the `Buffer` data into an array of strings instead, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

UNICODE_STRING testStr;
// fill testStr as needed...

std::vector<std::wstring> wStrArr;

std::wstring wStr(testStr.Buffer, testStr.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));
std::wstring::size_type startidx = 0;
do
{
    std::wstring::size_type idx = wStr.find(L'\0', startidx);
    if (idx == std::wstring::npos)
    {
        if (startidx < wStr.size())
        {
            if (startidx > 0)
                wStrArr.push_back(wStr.substr(startidx));
            else
                wStrArr.push_back(wStr);
        }
        break;
    }
    wStrArr.push_back(wStr.substr(startidx, idx-startidx));
    startidx = idx + 1;
}
while (true);

// use wStrArr as needed...
```

Or:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

UNICODE_STRING testStr;
// fill testStr as needed...

std::vector<std::wstring> wStrArr;

WCHAR *pStart = testStr.Buffer;
WCHAR *pEnd = pStart + (testStr.Length / sizeof(WCHAR));

do
{
    WCHAR *pFound = std::find(pStart, pEnd, L'\0');
    if (pFound == pEnd)
    {
        if (pStart < pEnd)
            wStrArr.push_back(std::wstring(pStart, pEnd-pStart));
        break;
    }
    wStrArr.push_back(std::wstring(pStart, pFound-pStart));
    pStart = pFound + 1;
}
while (true);

// use wStrArr as needed...
```

Comment: [std::string::c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns a pointer to `const`.

Answer (score 1):

A [UNICODE_STRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518.aspx) is a structure, that stores both character data as well as its length. As such, it allows for embedded NUL characters, just like a `std::wstring`, for example.

A C-style string (e.g. `wchar_t*`), on the other hand, does not store an explicit string length. By convention, it is terminated by a NUL character. It's length is implied. A corollary of this is, that it cannot contain embedded NUL characters.

That means that you cannot convert from `UNICODE_STRING` to `wchar_t*` without losing the length information. You have to either store the length explicitly, alongside the `wchar_t*` pointer, or establish rules for interpretation, that allow to recalculate the length (e.g. by interpreting the character sequence as a double-null-terminated string)<sup>1)</sup>.

---

Additional information:

- [What is the format of a double-null-terminated string with no strings?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091008-00/?p=16443)
- [Why double-null-terminated strings instead of an array of pointers to strings?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110511-00/?p=10693)

---

<sup>1)</sup> *The debugger will interpret a `wchar_t*` as a zero-terminated string. If you want to see the entire sequence, you need to explicitly provide the array size using a [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx).*